# Django static directory for apache deployment

Tags: python, django, apache

My apache root directory is

`/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/`
and there are some projects not only `django`, `laravel` etc..

my apache setting is this.

```
LoadFile "/Users/whitebear/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib"
LoadModule wsgi_module "/Users/whitebear/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py37.cpython-37m-darwin.so"
WSGIScriptAlias /mypythonapp /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/mypythonapp/mypythonapp/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /Users/whitebear/anaconda3
WSGIPythonPath /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/mypythonapp

<Directory /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/mypythonapp>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/mypythonapp/satic/
<Directory /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/mypythonapp/static>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then in this case I want to put the static file for mypythonapp here.

```
httproot - mypythonapp - mypythonapp
                         polls
                         template
                         static //here
```

So, I do like this in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "mypythonapp/static")
```

and then, `python manage.py collectstatic`

fils are gatheres under static directory.

but when accessing `localhost/mypythonapp/admin/`

in html
these link doesn't work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/dashboard.css">
```

There are files in

`/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/mypythonapp/static/admin/css/base.css`
`/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/mypythonapp/static/admin/css/dashboard.css`

Comment: When you access `href="/static/admin/css/base.css"` from browser - it should go to apache - then django - and show error somewhere. Check logs. Is alias for `/static/` - .../s__a__tic/ correct?

Comment: apache log returns 404 error `::1 - - [28/Dec/2019:11:14:41 +0630] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 223`

Comment: It was simply because of typo.... `mypythonapp/satic/` -> `mypythonapp/static/`